# Unmarshalling JSON with unknown property with null value

Tags: java, jersey, moxy

I'm using MOXy to unmarshall incoming JSON to my Jersey API. I have a POJO with three properties: databaseName, initialQuery, and runQueryAsUser. I have a client sending me a POST where the JSON has an additional property that I don't need, secureQuery. When the value of secureQuery is null, MOXy spits back a null object. When the value of secureQuery is the empty string, MOXy returns a valid object with the three properties set and secureQuery correctly ignored. The only annotation the POJO has is `@XmlRootElement(name = "InitialQuery")`.

Is this a bug, or is there a setting somewhere I have to flip?

Method Signature:

```
public Response createSecuredQuery(final InitialQueryBean initialQuery) {
```

Null InitialQuery object:

```
{
    "databaseName":"MyDatabase",
    "initialQuery":"select 1",
    "runQueryAsUser":"bob",
    "secureQuery":null
}
```

Good InitialQuery object:

```
{
    "databaseName":"MyDatabase",
    "initialQuery":"select 1",
    "runQueryAsUser":"bob",
    "secureQuery":""
}
```

Comment: trying to naively deserialize either of your inputs using moxy returns "A descriptor with default root element databaseName was not found in the project". are you positive there's no outer wrapping json with {"InitialQuery" : {[your input]}} ?

Comment: Can you not use something like "objectMapper.getSerializationConfig().setSerializationInclusion(JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL)" and objectMapper.configure(DeserializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)" to handle this? Also "Jackson" json provider gives two annotiations which you can use on top of the POJO and it will take of nulls and unknown properties. Like "@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)" and "@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)".

Comment: @radai Yes, I am certain. If that were the case, then neither input would work, since they are formatted the same way.

Comment: @ripudam I'm using MOXy, not Jackson. I'm familiar with the features of Jackson, but that doesn't help me with my problem.

Comment: There is a bug open for this issue: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=487176

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very familiar with MOXy, but your reference to `@XmlRootElement` suggests that you're using JAXB annotations to control your marshalling. Try adding the following property to your POJO:

```
@XmlAnyElement(lax="true")
public Object[] unknown; // name it whatever you want
```

This will basically be a catch-all for any values that are received but not covered by any other declared/annotated property in your POJO.  See the [JAXB documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlAnyElement.html) for more details.

The similar `@XmlAnyAttribute` might also be of use, depending on how MOXy is translating the input (to *elements* or to *attributes*).  There's a bit of ambiguity because these annotations were designed for marshalling to/from XML, not JSON.

Comment: Well, that's distinctly suboptimal, but at least it sounds like it will work. I'm hoping somebody comes back with a better solution.

Comment: Unless MOXy offers a configuration option to ignore unknown properties (i.e. as the Jackson object mapper framework does), you have to do some kind of "suboptimal" workaround.  I did a quick Google search and a method-based version of the above is detailed here: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/extensible-models-with-eclipselink-jaxb.html

Answer (score -1):

Apart from @XMLRootELement, use @XmlElement for all the properties in the pojo.

For the property **secureQuery**, use **@XmlElement(defaultValue="")**.

This will provide some value in case its a null.

See this link:
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElement.html#defaultValue%28%29

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. I don't want to provide the property. I want to ignore it when the client sends it to me.

Comment: Which was resolved in 2010, and is Jersey when I'm using MOXy.

Comment: See the resolution is wont fix and they have left it like that.

Comment: Try using ValidationEventHandler.Please see this link:http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/12/jaxb-and-marshalunmarshal-schema.html